# Modeling many-to-many relationships in mongodb using embedded documents to achieve better search performance

Tags: java, mongodb

**Background:**

I am trying to model a many-to-many relationship using the embedded document model.

The reason behind choosing mongodb is because the schema is dynamic as the platform deals with various products and services.

The application when logged in by an user bootstraps all the information of a user. But, all the queries such as update,search are majorly done on the products and services associated with users on the platform.

**Problem Statement:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = { "id", "password" })
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private Sex sex;
    private List<String> tags;

}

public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private List<User> users;
}

public class Service{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Initially i thought of making users as embedded documents within products and services.  The reason behind choosing the embedded document design is to avoid multiple queries during the search.

But, I also realized that when a user logs in to the application i need to have all the user related information which needs to be bootstrapped. The design seems to be getting complicated.

I would like to understand if this scenario could be handled in a better way. Anyone who has already solved this situation?

The queries i would like to perform are

Find:

```
db.products.find({"name": /.*m.*/})
```

Update:

```
 .update(Products:{$elemMatch:{Bag:"charollette"}}, {$set: {'Products.$.Name':"Charollette blue"}});
```

Insert:

```
db.products.insertOne( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );
```

Comment: On the side: consider single collection for both `Product` and `Service` documents - their structure is identical, just add `String type` field (with valid values `product` and `service`) and you will query one collection instead of 2 queries to 2 collections.

Comment: @wscourage thanks, it makes lot of sense.

Comment: In general, your question is not clear enough for me; try updating it with **all** the queries you need to do for every collection you create, for example "User: update, create, delete, addProduct, removeProduct". Then decide on the model.